# Infer type from void* variable

Tags: c, type-inference, void-pointers

Suppose I have a `struct` like

```
typedef struct __item {
    void **data;
    int length;
} item_array;
```

representing a kind of "generic array".

Is there any way I could infer the type of elements pointed by `data` `struct` member, without storing this information in my `struct`?

Comment: No.  It is just a chunk of memory.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I was afraid that would be the answer :(

Comment: This is one of those places C++ generics shine. Even if they wouldn't you'd still have RTTI.

Comment: Depends. You'd have to store that information *somewhere*, but not necessarily in the elements themselves - you could have a map from address to type, or something like that. If that information is nowhere, then obviously you can't magically get it out of nowhere.

Comment: @harold only if there was a type information in data itself.

Comment: before c++ we used to routinely store type information at the top of structs to achieve some sort of polymorphism. theres no reason you couldn't do this here

Comment: @SteveCox could you please explain how would this method work?

Comment: @Mauren I would, but its too much for the comments. This actually shows up in a couple places in the linux kernel, I might go digging for examples to link to.

Answer (score 1):

In C, there is no mechanism available to do this.